# NOT operator doesn't work in query lucene

Tags: lucene, operator-keyword, not-operator

I use lucene version 3.0.3.0, but some expression that i search, doesn't work properly. for example if i search "!Fiesta OR Astra" on field "Model", "vauxhallAstra" is returned only and "fordFocus" is not returned. my code is below:

```
var fordFiesta = new Document();

        fordFiesta.Add(new Field("Id", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        fordFiesta.Add(new Field("Make", "Ford", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        fordFiesta.Add(new Field("Model", "Fiesta", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));



        var fordFocus = new Document();

        fordFocus.Add(new Field("Id", "2", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        fordFocus.Add(new Field("Make", "Ford", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        fordFocus.Add(new Field("Model", "Focus", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));



        var vauxhallAstra = new Document();

        vauxhallAstra.Add(new Field("Id", "3", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        vauxhallAstra.Add(new Field("Make", "Vauxhall", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        vauxhallAstra.Add(new Field("Model", "Astra", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));







        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\LuceneIndex"));

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);





        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

        writer.AddDocument(fordFiesta);

        writer.AddDocument(fordFocus);

        writer.AddDocument(vauxhallAstra);


        writer.Optimize();                       

        writer.Close();

        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
        Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

        var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Model", analyzer);
        var query = queryParser.Parse("!Fiesta OR Astra");

        Console.WriteLine("Searching for: " + query.ToString());
        TopDocs resultDocs = indexSearch.Search(query, 200);            
        Console.WriteLine("Results Found: " + resultDocs.MaxScore);

        var hits = resultDocs.ScoreDocs;
        foreach (var hit in hits)
        {
            var documentFromSearcher = indexSearch.Doc(hit.Doc);
            Console.WriteLine(documentFromSearcher.Get("Make") + " " + documentFromSearcher.Get("Model"));
        }

        indexSearch.Close();
        directory.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!Fiesta OR Astra` doesn't mean what you think it means.  The `!Fiesta` portion does NOT mean, "get everything except Fiesta", as you might expect, but rather more like "forbid Fiesta".  A `NOT` term in a Lucene query only filters out results, it does not find anything.

The only query you have defined that will actually fetch results is `Astra`.  So everything containing Astra will be found, then anything with `Fiesta` will be filtered out.

In order to perform the query I believe you are expecting, you would need something like:

```
Astra OR (*:* !Fiesta)
```

`*:*` as a `MatchAllDocsQuery`.  Since you do need to match all the documents to perform this sort of query, it can be expected to perform poorly.

---

Confusing interpretation of "boolean" logic like this are why I really don't like AND/OR/NOT syntax for Lucene.  +/- is much clearer, more powerful, and doesn't introduce the oddball gotchas like this.

[This excellent article on the topic](http://searchhub.org/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not/) clarifies somewhat why you should be thinking in terms of `MUST`/`MUST_NOT`/`SHOULD`, rather than traditional boolean logic.

Comment: you saved me a headache